# Find the index of table column with specific id

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

This is my table

```
                 <table>
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>0001</th>
                                <th class="hidden">0002</th>
                                <th id="myColumn">0003</th>
                                <th>0004</th>
                     ...........
                     ...........
                 </table>
```

I want to get the index of `th` with id `myColumn`. The result should be `2`.
**Note** : my table has hidden column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) directly on the element:

```
$('#myColumn').index()
```

**Demo**

```js
console.log($('#myColumn').index())
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>0001</th>
      <th class="hidden">0002</th>
      <th id="myColumn">0003</th>
      <th>0004</th>
    </tr>
    </head>
</table>
```

Comment: my table has hidden column, I've edited my question

Comment: @StevenSann look at my demo, still the same result

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.I think this is what you want.

```js
var index = $("#myColumn").index();
console.log("column index  " +index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>0001</th>
                                <th class="hidden">0002</th>
                                <th id="myColumn">0003</th>
                                <th>0004</th>
                                </thead>
                    
                 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As in many, many cases, this is easier to achieve and also much cleaner with vanilla JS.

The native DOM API has this stored at each table cell in `HTMLTableCellElement.prototype.cellIndex`. The table rows have `HTMLTableRowElement.prototype.rowIndex` (in case you care about the row number):

```js
console.log(myColumn.cellIndex);
console.log(myColumn.parentElement.rowIndex);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>0001</th>
      <th class="hidden">0002</th>
      <th id="myColumn">0003</th>
      <th>0004</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```